# Connection string not available in azure app via environment

Tags: azure-configuration

I have a connection string I entered into the App Settings for my application. This setting was retrieving as expected up until today. Now, when I try to publish my application, the environment variable is not in the list of environment variables available from Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables. When I attempt to retrieve it from either builder.Configuration.ConnectionStrings() or Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable, I get a null string.

What would cause an environment variable to not get set? Everything seems as if it is configured properly.

Below is a screen shot from the App Settings, Configuration page show that the variable is set there.
[image]

Below is a screen shot from KUDU, showing that the environment variable CUSTOMCONNSTR_AppConfig does exist on the app service:
[image]

Below is the code that attempts to retrieve the connection string. I added the exception throw on string empty or null check to avoid any confusion over where the error is coming from:

```
static void ConfigurationEnvironmentVariablesNecessaryToInitializeServices(WebApplicationBuilder builder)
{
    // this section tries to get the connection string, which works locally from local secret store, but for some reason it was
    // not getting set via Azure App Settings. Thus the fallback to get the resulting environment variable which does seem to
    // be working in Azure.
    string issueIdentityAPIConfigConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppConfig");
    builder.Configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(issueIdentityAPIConfigConnectionString))
    {
        issueIdentityAPIConfigConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CUSTOMCONNSTR_AppConfig"); ;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(issueIdentityAPIConfigConnectionString))
    {
        throw new Exception("Connection string was null in both builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString(\"AppConfig\") and Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(\"CUSTOMCONNSTR_AppConfig\")");

    }
```

Below is the exception being thrown when I publish the app:

```
    Unhandled exception. System.Exception: Connection string was null in both builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppConfig") and Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CUSTOMCONNSTR_AppConfig")
       at Program.<<Main>$>g__ConfigurationEnvironmentVariablesNecessaryToInitializeServices|0_2(WebApplicationBuilder builder) in C:\Users\wayne\source\repos\IssueIdentity\IssueIdentityAPI\Program.cs:line 72
       at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Users\wayne\source\repos\IssueIdentity\IssueIdentityAPI\Program.cs:line 14
```

Comment: If anybody wants to answer it is academic at this point. I gave up on using Enviornment.GetEnvironmentVariable and instead am using dependency injection on my controllers to get the IConfiguration object. That gets all the app settings.
This annoying because what I was trying to do was store the connection string so I could use the ApplicationConfiguration service and retrieve secrets from there. The fact I had this working and suddenly it stopped is troubling to me.

Comment: Your screenshot seems to be the older version of Azure App Service.You can see few updates/changes in the UI of App Service.

Comment: Options to add App Settings/Connection Strings has been moved from Configuration Section. There is a new option to add Environment Variables under settings.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2vRm.png)

Comment: I have added the key-value pair under [Connection Strings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUPO4.png).You can see the value is available under [Environment Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIw2p.png)

Comment: You need to update the Azure Portal to get the latest version.If possible, try to create a new Azure App Service and deploy the app to the new AppService.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you run the code locally you get the same error.

[image]

- This is because while publishing the App, the application will build and load the code locally.
- And the code which you have provided does not satisfy any of the condition as you are not setting the `Connection String` in either `appsettings.json` or in the `Environment Variable` (Which I understood this from your previous question).

I have provided 2 workarounds , check and follow any one.

***Way 1 :***

- As we are facing issue with the given code while publishing from Visual Studio.
- Open the Project Folder in VSCode and deploy the code from there.

[image]

- App will be published even if you have errors in the Code(as we are unable to run locally, better to choose this option).

[image]

***Way 2:***

- Add the sample/dummy connection string in `appsettings.json` file.

```cs
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "AppConfig": "Sample"
  }
```

- Now publish the App.
- Navigate to the KUDU Console (`site\wwwroot`), you can see the `appsettings.json` file.
  As you don't want to set any values in your Configuration file.
  delete the Connection String Section from the appsettings.json`.
- Now save and run the deployed URL.
- To confirm whether we have value for `CUSTOMCONNSTR_AppConfig` in  `GetEnvironmentVariable`, write the below line of code in `Index.cshtml` before publishing the App.

```cs
@Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CUSTOMCONNSTR_AppConfig")
```

You can see Iam able to retrieve the value using `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CUSTOMCONNSTR_AppConfig")`

***Env Variables:***

[image]

***Output:***

[image]